# Use Terraform on Google Cloud SQL Postgres to create a Replication Slot

Tags: postgresql, terraform, google-cloud-sql, database-replication, google-datastream

Overall I'm trying to create a Datastream Connection to a Postgres database in Cloud SQL.

As I'm trying to configure it all through Terraform, I'm stuck on how I should create a Replication Slot. [This guide](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) explains how to do it through the Postgres Client and running SQL commands, but I thought there might be a way to do it in the Terraform configuration directly.

Example SQL that I would like to replicate in Terraform:

```
ALTER USER [CURRENT_USER] WITH REPLICATION;
CREATE PUBLICATION [PUBLICATION_NAME] FOR ALL TABLES;
SELECT PG_CREATE_LOGICAL_REPLICATION_SLOT('[REPLICATION_SLOT_NAME]', 'pgoutput');
```

If not, does anyone know how to run the Postgres SQL commands against the Cloud SQL database through Terraform?

I have setup the Datastream and Postgres connection for all other parts. I'm expecting that there is a Terraform setting I'm missing or a way to run Postgres commands against the Google Cloud SQL Postgres database.

Comment: No solution yet ?

Comment: Did you try to use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest terraform provider?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no terraform resource for specifying a replication slot on a google_sql_database_instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).